# How to always run UPDATE FROM despite missing records in the source table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, left-join, postgresql-10

I have prepared [a simplified test case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/22jfWnsvqD8hVeFPXsyLbV/0) for my question -

[image: screenshot]

In PostgreSQL 10.6 there are 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
  uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        created       timestamptz NOT NULL,
        visited       timestamptz NOT NULL,
        ip            inet        NOT NULL,
        lat           double precision,
        lng           double precision
  );

  CREATE TABLE geoip (
        block   inet    PRIMARY KEY,
        lat     double precision,
        lng     double precision
);

CREATE INDEX ON geoip USING SPGIST (block);
```

which are filled with the following test data:

```
INSERT INTO users (created, visited, ip) VALUES
  (now(), now(), '1.2.3.4'::inet),
  (now(), now(), '1.2.3.5'::inet),
  (now(), now(), '1.2.3.6'::inet);

INSERT INTO geoip (block, lat, lng) VALUES
 ('1.2.3.0/24', -33.4940, 143.2104),
 ('10.0.0.0/8', 34.6617, 133.9350);
```

Then in a stored function I run the following UPDATE command -

```
UPDATE users u SET
    visited = now(),
    ip      = '10.10.10.10'::inet,
    lat     = i.lat,
    lng     = i.lng
FROM geoip i
WHERE u.uid = 1 AND '10.10.10.10'::inet <<= i.block;
```

(the 1 and the ip address are actually `in_uid` and `in_ip` parameters in my stored function).

The above query works well and updates all 4 fields in the `users` table.

However the following query does not work as intended and does not update any fields, because there is no matching `block` in the `geoip` table found:

```
UPDATE users u SET
    visited = now(),               -- HOW TO ALWAYS UPDATE THIS FIELD?
    ip      = '20.20.20.20'::inet, -- HOW TO ALWAYS UPDATE THIS FIELD?
    lat     = i.lat,
    lng     = i.lng
FROM geoip i
WHERE u.uid = 2 AND '20.20.20.20'::inet <<= i.block;
```

The field `visited` and `ip` however should be always updated - regardless if the `block` was found or not.

Kind of LEFT JOIN, but for UPDATE - how to achieve this please?

The only workaround that I could think of is -

```
UPDATE users SET
    visited = now(),
    ip      = '20.20.20.20'::inet,
    lat     = (SELECT lat FROM geoip WHERE '20.20.20.20'::inet <<= block),
    lng     = (SELECT lng FROM geoip WHERE '20.20.20.20'::inet <<= block)
WHERE uid = 2;
```

But that would run the same subquery twice (correct?) and my `geoip` table is already slow with 3073410 records (and that is why I am trying to *cache* its `lat` and `lng` values in the `users` table on each user login event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Andrew Gierth at the [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87k1jbno3w.fsf%40news-spur.riddles.org.uk) mailing list has provided an SQL-only answer:

```
UPDATE users u SET 
    visited = now(),
    ip = v.ip,
    lat = i.lat,
    lng = i.lng
FROM (VALUES ('20.20.20.20'::inet)) v(ip)
      LEFT JOIN geoip i ON (v.ip <<= i.block)
WHERE u.uid = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (maybe stupid) is to add `u.uid = 2 OR (u.uid = 2 AND '20.20.20.20'::inet <<= i.block)` insted of that `AND` condition.. and maybe change `lat     = i.lat`, to `lat     = NULLIF(i.lat, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to lookup the `geoip` big table for twice:

```
-- start transaction
-- some stuff

UPDATE users u SET
    visited = now(),               
    ip      = '20.20.20.20'::inet 
WHERE u.uid = 2;  -- fast because is from pk

UPDATE users u SET
    lat     = i.lat,
    lng     = i.lng
FROM geoip i
WHERE u.uid = 2 AND '20.20.20.20'::inet <<= i.block;

-- more stuff
-- commit tx
```

Comment: That will surely work, but I was hoping to achieve it in a single UPDATE (abusing any PostgreSQL black magic would be ok for me too)

Comment: why? ___________

Comment: I am hoping that a single UPDATE would take less time than two.

Comment: In my opinion this is two different operations. Also, first query has no cost (almost)

Comment: In my opinion, inside a function, the cost of first query is negligible.